# Convince macOS and FireFox that I speak English

Tags: macos, firefox, language

On macOS and FireFox I have always installed everything in an English locale and set everything I can find to English, yet the browser and OS both frequently seem to change languages at random times to the language of my VPN IP. Can I fix this?

Here's what's been checked / set thusfar:

1. Apple menu > "System Preferences" > "Language & Region" (Shows English only and Region = United States)
2. No other languages set as "Application languages" on the OS
3. No "translation languages" downloaded on the OS
4. In FireFox: Menu > Settings > Language is set to English. "Set Alternatives..." shows Deutsch as the 2nd choice behind English and it won't let me remove it.
5. browser.translation.detectLanguage  is set to False
6. browser.translations.enable is set to False
7. intl.locale.requested had US-en, de. I removed de.
8. intl.multilingual.aboutWelcome.languageMismatchEnabled  is set to False
9. services.sync.prefs.sync.intl.accept_languages is set to False

Comment: All your steps are about what Firefox sends to sites. Is this only about web content? Because you wrote "browser and OS […] change languages". Does the OS actually randomly switch its display language?

Comment: @DanielB Yes, this is about the interface of the OS itself as well as the browser. For instance, all system folders in Finder display in the foreign languages. Not just web content. Also the button choices on pop-ups within the browser (and also the web content, but I can be more forgiving about that, as I understand sites may use the IP to set the language). The list is just everything language-related that I could find myself or that ChatGPT could think of.

Comment: Since the OS is doing it too.  Focus on that first.

Comment: @BlindSpots It's a good point. I'm just not sure what else to check. It's supposed to just be the Language & Region setting, right?

Comment: @Hack-R unfortunately not a macOS user just my 2 cents based on the significance of an OS-dependent change vs a browser issue.  Is it always the same language (you didn't specify one) or does it move based on VPN IP region?  Also, please edit question to include OS version.